# Constructing an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

I want to construct an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a prime that can be written as $4k+1$. My attempt is as follow: we can assume that this polynomial is of the form  ${x^2} + ax + b$ for some $a,b \in {\mathbb{F}_p}$. So for all $\lambda  \in {F_p}$, $p$ doesn't divide ${\lambda ^2} + a\lambda  + b$. It follows that ${\lambda ^2}$ is not equal to $a\lambda  + b
\bmod p$. If we can find some $a,b \in {\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that $a\lambda  + b$ is a nonresidue for all $\lambda  \in {F_p}$, it is ok. But I cannot. I wait your response.

Comment: You could just pick $a=0$ and $b$ to be a quadratic non-residue no?

Comment: You are right but what about $b$? Jake.

Comment: @egrtomath So, your question is how to construct explicitly an element $b$ that is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$? Or is it just prove that there is such an element?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331075/if-p-equiv-1-mod4-is-prime-how-to-find-a-quadratic-nonresidue-modulo-p.

Comment: For the present, Jake's answer is enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2-b$ is irreducible mod $p$ iff $b$ is a quadratic non-residue mod $p$.

Since half the classes mod $p$ are quadratic non-residues, there are plenty of choices for $b$.

Explicitly finding one $b$ for a given $p$ is another matter, although it is usually quite small:
see [A053760](https://oeis.org/A053760). In particular, the smallest quadratic non-residue mod $p$ is at most $\sqrt{p}+1$ ([proof](http://number.subwiki.org/wiki/Smallest_quadratic_nonresidue_is_less_than_square_root_plus_one)).

Comment: See also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/.