# Computational complexity of finding a quadratic nonresidue modulo a prime

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

For a prime $N$, there are precisely $\frac{N-1}{2}$ quadratic nonresidues modulo $N$. Picking a base randomly, one would expect a $1/2$ chance of choosing a quadratic nonresidue. Excluding perfect squares, the expected chance would be slightly higher.

Utilizing quadratic reciprocity, one can reasonably quickly determine whether a randomly chosen base is a quadratic nonresidue, lets say with asymptotic complexity $O(Q)$.

It is also known that the smallest quadratic nonresidue is about less than $\sqrt{N}$, so choosing bases randomly one has worst case complexity of ${O}(\sqrt{N}Q)=\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$. However, the actual "chance" that this worst case occurs is astronomically small. This leads me to believe that it should be possible to get a better worst case runtime then $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$.

Is there any deterministic runtime better than $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$?

**Note:** Assuming the GRH, one knows that the smallest quadratic nonresidue is less than $ln^2(N)$ roughly, so assuming this we have ${O}(ln^2(N)Q)$. I am asking for a solution without assumption.

Comment: this is an area where what happens is generally much, much better than what can be proved. It is not difficult to program the Jacobi symbol; run some tests

Comment: One thing that will happen: the first nonresidue is a prime.

Comment: Ya, but I feel like the computational complexity of determining primality in general and the distribution of primes will make this not that much of an improvement.

Comment: If your prime is $3$ modulo $4$, then $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue. If your prime is $5$ modulo $12$, then $3$ is a nonresidue. You can make up tests like this ad infinitum. But I'm pretty sure that in general, and without any unproved hypotheses, no one knows how to do any better than to test random numbers until you find one that works.

Comment: This may help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50540/how-does-one-find-a-non-quadratic-residue-modulo-p also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331075/if-p-equiv-1-mod4-is-prime-how-to-find-a-quadratic-nonresidue-modulo-p

Comment: It's actually known that the smallest quadratic nonresidue is smaller than $cN^{0.152}$ for some constant $c$ (this is due to Burgess).

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic residuosity (QR) and Quadratic non-residuosity (QNR) are both in NP$\cap$co-NP [1]. If you however think of QR as the problem of finding solutions to the congruence equation

$$x^2=a (\bmod b)$$

in the natural numbers, subject to the additional constraint that $x\le c$, then the problem becomes NP-complete [2]; the corresponding complementary problem is then complete in co-NP. But then, if the modulus is prime, this problem becomes a problem in P [3], assuming the truth of the extended Riemann hypothesis.

Caveat: The well known text on complexity by Arora and Barak has a mistake [4] in example 8.9 where it says that QNR is *not* known to be in NP.

[1] Cai, J. Y., and Threlfall, R., A note on quadratic residuosity and UP, Information Processing Letters 9-3 (2004) 127-131

[2] Manders K. L, and Adleman, L., NP-complete decision problems for binary quadratics, Journal of Computer and Systems Science 16, (1978), 168-184

[3] Garey, M., and and Johnson, D. S., Computers and Intractability: a Guide to the Theory of NP-completeness, Freeman and Company, (1979)

[4] Barak, B. personal communication 28 July 2023.